# Multithreaded Web Crawler in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, web-crawler

I am trying to write a Multithreaded Web Crawler in Java using Jsoup.I have a Java Class "Master" which creates 6 threads(5 for crawling and 1 for maintenance of queues) ,and 3 queues namely "to_do","to_do_next"(to be done in next iteration) and "done"(final links).
I am using sunchronized locks on shared queues.The idea is as soon as all the 5 threads find the "to_do" queue empty they notify a maintenance thread which does some work and notify these threads back.But the problem is the program is getting blocked sometimes (so i assume there is some race condition I am not able to take care of)....also upon checking I found that not all threads are getting notified by maintenace thread.so is it possible that some notify signals might be lost??

Code for Master class

```
private Queue<String> to_do = new LinkedList<String>();
private Queue<String> done= new LinkedList<String>(); 
private Queue<String> to_do_next = new LinkedList<String>();
private int level = 1;
private Object lock1 = new Object();
private Object lock2 = new Object();
private Object lock3 = new Object();
private static Thread maintenance;

public static Master mref;
public static Object wait1 = new Object();
public static Object wait2 = new Object();
public static Object wait3 = new Object();
public static int flag = 5;
public static int missedSignals = -1;

public boolean checkToDoEmpty(){
    return to_do.isEmpty();
}

public int getLevel() {
    return level;
}

public void incLevel() {
    this.level++;
}

public static void interrupt() {
     maintenance.interrupt();
}

public void transfer() {
    to_do = to_do_next;
}

public String accessToDo() {
    synchronized(lock1){
        String tmp = to_do.peek();
        if(tmp != null)
            tmp = to_do.remove();
        return tmp;
    }
}

public void addToDoNext(String url){
    synchronized(lock2){
        to_do_next.add(url);
    }
}

public void addDone(String string) {
    synchronized(lock3){
        done.add(string);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args){

    Master m = new Master();
    mref = m;
    URL startUrl = null;
    try {
        startUrl = new URL("http://cse.iitkgp.ac.in");
    }catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Worker(1));
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Worker(2));
    Thread t3 = new Thread(new Worker(3));
    Thread t4 = new Thread(new Worker(4));
    Thread t5 = new Thread(new Worker(5));
    maintenance = new Thread(new MaintenanceThread());

    m.to_do.add(startUrl.toString());

    maintenance.start();
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
    t4.start();
    t5.start();

    try {
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
        t4.join();
        t5.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /*for(String s:m.done)
        System.out.println(s);
    for(String s:m.to_do)
        System.out.println(s);*/
}
```

Code for Worker threads

```
public void run() {

    while(Master.mref.getLevel() != 3){

        if(!Master.mref.checkToDoEmpty()){

            String url = Master.mref.accessToDo();

            if(url != null && url.contains("iitkgp") && url.contains("http://")){

                try {
                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                    org.jsoup.select.Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

                    for(org.jsoup.nodes.Element l: links){
                        Master.mref.addToDoNext(l.attr("abs:href").toString());
                    }

                    Master.mref.addDone(url);
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    System.out.println(url);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                continue;
            }   
        }
        //System.out.println("thread " + id + " about to notify on wait1");
        synchronized(Master.wait1){
            Master.wait1.notify();
            Master.missedSignals++;
        }
        synchronized(Master.wait2){
            try {
                Master.wait2.wait();
                System.out.println("thread " + id + " coming out of wait2");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
    System.out.println("Terminating " + id + " thread");
    Master.flag--;
    if(Master.flag == 0)
        Master.interrupt();
}
```

Code for Maintenace thread

```
while(Master.flag != 0){

        try {
            synchronized(Master.wait1){
                if(Master.missedSignals != -1){
                    count += Master.missedSignals;
                    Master.missedSignals = -1;
                }
                while(count != 5){
                    Master.wait1.wait();
                    if(Master.missedSignals != -1)
                        count += Master.missedSignals;
                    Master.missedSignals = -1;
                    count++;
                }
                count = 0;
            }
            //System.out.println("in between");
            Master.mref.incLevel();
            Master.mref.transfer();
            synchronized(Master.wait2){
                Master.wait2.notifyAll();
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Mainta thread gone");
```

Comment: If you find my answer acceptable, may I ask you to accept it please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your design is way too complicated

i suggest using for your to_do queue the following: LinkedBlockingQueue

This is a blocking queue, which means that your threads will ask for an object from the queue and only when one will appear they will get the object, till then they will stay blocking.

Just use the following methods to put and take objects in the queue: put() & take()

Please look at the following two links for more explanations on this special queue:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/linkedblockingqueue.html

Now, your only concern is killing the threads when they are finished with their work, for that I suggest the following:

```
boolean someThreadStillAlive = true;
while (someThreadStillAlive) {
  someThreadStillAlive = false;
  Thread.sleep(200);
  for (Thread t : fetchAndParseThreads) {
    someThreadStillAlive = someThreadStillAlive || t.isAlive();
  }
}
```

This will occur in your main code block, where it will loop & sleep till all threads are finished.

Ohh, instead of take(), you can use poll(int timeout...) where it will wait for the timeout to finish and if no new object is inserted into the queue it will kill the thread.

All of the above, were used successfully in my own crawler.